# If Hogwarts's location is a secret, how did Durmstrang and Beauxbatons find it in the Goblet of Fire?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

As referenced in "Hogwarts: A History", the location of the school is unknown due to a number of various charms and protections. Igor Karkaroff even interrupts a conversation between Krum and Hermione when Krum starts mentioning the lakes and mountains that surround their castle. Karkaroff mentions "don't give away any more information, otherwise your pretty little friend will know exactly where we are". I'm just curious that if the secretive locations of schools are so closely guarded, then how did Beauxbatons and Durmstrang know where to go?

Comment: The location of Hogwarts isn't *secret* - the locations of other schools are. Also, one would expect the organizers of the Triwizard Tournament to share some road maps, no?